# my project always perform a force close

Tags: android

this is the code...

this is the first class which the main question was given..
    package com.turtle;

```
import com.turtle.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class Question extends Activity{



    protected static final String Level1 = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question);





        Button chkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bresult);
        final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etext);
        final TextView tvresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvresult2);



        chkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String answer = "Marianas Trench";
                String answer2 = "marianas trench";
                String answer3 = "MARIANAS TRENCH";

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("ANSWER", answer);

                String check = input.getText().toString();
                if (check.contentEquals(answer)){

                      b.putString("ANSWER", answer);

                      Intent intObj = new Intent(Question.this, Level1.class);
                      intObj.putExtras(b);
                      startActivity(intObj);

                    }else if (check.contentEquals(answer2)){

                      b.putString("ANSWER", answer);

                      Intent intObj = new Intent(Question.this, Level1.class);
                      intObj.putExtras(b);

                      startActivity(intObj);

                    }else if (check.contentEquals(answer3)){

                      b.putString("ANSWER", answer);

                      Intent intObj = new Intent(Question.this, Level1.class);
                      intObj.putExtras(b);

                    startActivity(intObj);

                    }else{

                    }



    }
        });
    }
}
```

this was the second class which consist of image button and if clicked, it will proceed to the question page....

```
package com.turtle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Level1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.setContentView(R.layout.level1);   



ImageButton btl1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.l1);
btl1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent myIntent= new Intent("com.turtleexploration.QUESTION");
        startActivity(myIntent);

    }
});
ImageButton btl2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.l2);
btl2.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent myIntent= new Intent("com.turtleexploration.QUESTION2");
        startActivity(myIntent);

    }
});
ImageButton btBacklvl1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.backlvl1);
btBacklvl1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent myIntent= new Intent("com.turtleexploration.NEWGAME");
        startActivity(myIntent);

    }
});



    }

    }
```

Comment: You need to be more clear as to what your question is, what the symptoms are and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay, Im trying to accomplish a Q&A game that if the player is correct.. then the Image of a Button from a class was changed.. As of now, I can do it because of many errors... I try for the past few weeks all of my best but im still a newbie in android or in java...

Comment: What goes wrong? What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: Where exactly are you having the error?, please show your Logcat.

Comment: the issue has been solved with try and catch.. but then.. my project resulting with no output.. aside of giving the answers.. the button in the second class has image that must have change if the answer from the first class was correct

Answer (score 0):

I assume yout first activity starts and then you ve got an FC when you click on your Button.

You may have other problems but you have  declared Level1 as a String object. 
If you don't use it, remove it or rename it.  In the Intent constructor Level1.class should refer to the class of your second activity.

```
  Intent intObj = new Intent(Question.this, Level1.class);
```

And finally be sure you have declared Level1 activity in your manifest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174629/how-to-change-the-image-of-a-button/15175908#comment21377795_15175908

Comment: Look at you post. First field of your Question Activity
protected static final String Level1 = null;

Comment: okay i fix it.. it is okay now.. but there still no result of a button changing image.